# sharing data with heroku apps

Tags: heroku, memcached

Hi what is the recommended way of sharing data in heroku apps.

The reason why I ask is that I have a scheduler app which runs a process every 5 mins and places data in a memcache (memcachier).

I would then like another servlet based app to be able to read that same memcache data and return it to the user.

I tried to do this but the data is returning null.

Would it be better to use a database or is there any other way of doing this.

Can the memcache be shared across dynos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, all these things are connected as attachable resources via your config variables.  It's perfectly OK to have many apps using the same attached resources.

http://www.12factor.net/backing-services

http://www.12factor.net/config